# Kephas has its own dependecy injection container. Why another framework, why not use an existing one?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, kephas

When taking a look at Kephas framework these days, I noticed it provides its own dependency injection container. There are so many dependency injection frameworks on the market now, why bring your own implementation? Isn't that just reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674745/does-anyone-know-about-kephas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kephas does not provide a DI/IoC container itself, it provides only an abstraction layer over DI/IoC containers, so that it can use composition itself without being bound to a specific implementation. What it does provide is an adapter for this abstraction layer for `System.Composition` in the Kephas.Composition.Mef package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kephas.Composition.Mef/). We planned also an adapter for `Autofac` but we didn't have the time to implement it to end.

Please note that this abstraction layer does come with some features unique to Kephas:

- Registered service implementations may be overridden, to leverage layered application architectures.
- Service contracts/interfaces drive the registration by the means of the `[*AppServiceContract]` attributes.

Also note that metadata support is a required feature for DI frameworks Kephas integrate with, which, in some cases, may impose limitations. For more information you can read here: https://github.com/kephas-software/kephas/wiki/Composition-and-Dependency-Injection.

Comment: Does this abstraction layer add an overhead and to which extent?

Comment: Any abstraction layer would add an overhead. In the second place, it depends on the adapter. In case of ```System.Composition```, resolving services does not add much of an overhead; registering services does a bit, by collecting all the services and service implementations based on the attributed model. But then again, you have to see for yourself in your particular case what does that mean.